# Calling LdrLoadDll from APC gives access violation

Tags: c, windows, kernel, driver

I have been making a kernel-level DLL injector for about two weeks. I have fought through a ton of bugs and learned a lot from them, but I am stuck at the final issue. When I insert my UserMode APC into a target process, the Normal Routine gets executed fine and works correctly with the exception of one line: calling `LdrLoadDll` routine to load my DLL into the target process. The target process crashes when `LdrLoadDll` gets called with access violation exception.

Here is the code for inserting the APC:

```
PTITANIUM_INJECTION_INFO InjectionInfo = FindInjectionInfo(ProcessId);

wchar_t DllPathBuffer[] = L"C:\\Users\\alber\\Desktop\\TestDLL.dll";
RtlInitUnicodeString(&InjectionInfo->DllPath, DllPathBuffer);

DbgPrint("\nTarget DLL Path: %wZ\n", InjectionInfo->DllPath);
DbgPrint("LdrLoadDllRoutine is at 0x%p\n", InjectionInfo->LdrLoadDllRoutine);

PEPROCESS pProcess;
PsLookupProcessByProcessId(ProcessId, &pProcess);

PETHREAD AvailableThread = FindAvailableThread(ProcessId);
if (!AvailableThread)
{
    DbgPrint("Failed to find available thread in target process\n\n");
    return;
}

KeAttachProcess(pProcess);
DbgPrint("Attached to Process\n\n");

PVOID DllPathBufferAddress = NULL;
SIZE_T DllPathBufferAddressSize = 4096;

NTSTATUS status0 = ZwAllocateVirtualMemory(NtCurrentProcess(), (PVOID*)&DllPathBufferAddress, 0, &DllPathBufferAddressSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(status0))
{
    DbgPrint("[-] Failed to allocate memory for dll path buffer, error code: 0x%X [-]\n", status0);
    KeDetachProcess();
    DbgPrint("Detached from process\n\n");

    return;
}

DbgPrint("Allocated 4096 bytes for DLL Path Buffer\n");

wcscpy(DllPathBufferAddress, LocalDllPathBuffer);
DbgPrint("Local DLL Path Buffer copied into usermode space: %ws\n", DllPathBufferAddress);

PVOID  ContextAddress = NULL;
SIZE_T ContextAllocationSize = 4096;

NTSTATUS status = ZwAllocateVirtualMemory(NtCurrentProcess(), &ContextAddress, 0, &ContextAllocationSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
{
    DbgPrint("[-] Failed to allocate memory for apc context, error code: 0x%X [-]\n", status);
    KeDetachProcess();
    DbgPrint("Detached from process\n\n");

    return;
}

DbgPrint("APC Context allocated in the target process at 0x%p\n", ContextAddress);

memcpy(ContextAddress, InjectionInfo, sizeof(TITANIUM_INJECTION_INFO));
DbgPrint("Context copied into the target process\n");

PVOID  NormalRoutineAddress = NULL;
SIZE_T NormalRoutineAllocationSize = (SIZE_T)((ULONG_PTR)NRStubFn - (ULONG_PTR)InjectorAPCNormalRoutine);
DbgPrint("Normal Routine function size: %i bytes\n", NormalRoutineAllocationSize);

status = ZwAllocateVirtualMemory(NtCurrentProcess(), &NormalRoutineAddress, 0, &NormalRoutineAllocationSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
{
    DbgPrint("[-] Failed to allocate memory for apc normal routine [-]\n");
    KeDetachProcess();
    DbgPrint("Detached from process\n\n");

    return;
}

DbgPrint("APC Normal Routine allocated in the target process at 0x%p\n", NormalRoutineAddress);

memcpy(NormalRoutineAddress, InjectorAPCNormalRoutine, NormalRoutineAllocationSize);
DbgPrint("Normal Routine copied into the target process\n");

PKAPC apc = (PKAPC)ExAllocatePool(NonPagedPool, sizeof(KAPC));
if (!apc)
{
    DbgPrint("Error: Unable to allocate the APC object.");
    KeDetachProcess();
    DbgPrint("Detached from process\n");
    return;
}

KeInitializeApc(apc, AvailableThread, OriginalApcEnvironment, KernelApc, NULL, (PKNORMAL_ROUTINE)NormalRoutineAddress, UserMode, ContextAddress);
DbgPrint("APC initialized\n");

KeInsertQueueApc(apc, NULL, NULL, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
DbgPrint("APC inserted into the queue\n");

/*LARGE_INTEGER delay;
delay.QuadPart = -200 * 10000;

for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
{
    DbgPrint("[***] InjectedInfo->Inject Real Value: %i [***]\n", ((PTITANIUM_INJECTION_INFO)ContextAddress)->Injected);

    if (!((PTITANIUM_INJECTION_INFO)ContextAddress)->Injected)
    {
        KeDelayExecutionThread(KernelMode, FALSE, &delay);
        DbgPrint("[*] InjectedInfo->Inject: FALSE | Retrying: %i [*]\n", i);
    }
    else
    {
        DbgPrint("[!] InjectedInfo->Inject: TRUE | DllBase: 0x%p [!]\n", ((PTITANIUM_INJECTION_INFO)ContextAddress)->DllBase);
        break;
    }
}*/

KeDetachProcess();
DbgPrint("Detached from process\n");

DbgPrint("\n");
```

And here is my Normal Routine:

```
VOID InjectorAPCNormalRoutine(PVOID Context, PVOID SysArg1, PVOID SysArg2)
{
    PTITANIUM_INJECTION_INFO InjectionInfo = (PTITANIUM_INJECTION_INFO)Context;
    
    InjectionInfo->LdrLoadDllRoutine(NULL, 0, &InjectionInfo->DllPath, &InjectionInfo->DllBase);
    InjectionInfo->Injected = TRUE;
}
```

I tried manually calling LdrLoadDll from a separate user-mode project and it worked perfectly. I also verified that the `LdrLoadDll` routine address is the same in both cases.

I genuinely don't know what to do anywhere and trust me that I've looked through all google searches I could come up with.

Here are some images from debugging and disassembly in case it could be useful:

[image: Disassembly]

[image]

Comment: The second image is from the manual injection?

Comment: Im not familiar with APC injection but if you're allocating the function into the process address space you'll almost certainly need to do so with the DLL path as well.

Comment: @Luke You are correct. I am doing two memory allocations inside the target process, one for the function (NormalRoutine) and the second for the apc context which is a struct that contains the DLL path inside it.

Comment: @Azeem The second image is just an extension of the first one that also shows the contents of registers and debug output of the driver.

Comment: Yes, but the UNICODE_STRING.Buffer points to a string in kernel address space. You need to copy it into user address space so it is accessible by LdrLoadDll.

Comment: @Luke OOOOOH, I am gonna try that right now.

Comment: @Luke, I implemented your solution, but surprisingly the error still occurs in the same place. After allocating the memory for APC context, I use ```memcpy(ContextAddress, InjectionInfo, sizeof(TITANIUM_INJECTION_INFO));
ContextAddress->DllPath.Buffer = UsermodeDLLPathBuffer;
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&ContextAddress->DllPath, ContextAddress->DllPath.Buffer);``` to initialize the unicode string inside usermode space with a proper buffer pointer, but it didn't work.

Comment: What does the updated code look like?

Comment: @Luke I edited the post with the updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to the problem myself. Apparently there was nothing wrong with my code, but the compiler was generating a bugged instruction. In my first screenshot right above the breakpointed `call` instruction, there is a `mov` instruction and it moves the correct `LdrLoadDll` function address into the rax register, but the next instruction calls some weird address instead of the proper address inside rax register.
I solved my problem by creating a separate .asm file and writing out the Normal Routine in assembly myself there. Here is the assembly code if anyone is interested:

```
NormalRoutineNativeAssembly proc

    mov         qword ptr [rsp+18h], r8
    mov         qword ptr [rsp+10h], rdx  
    sub         rsp, 48h  
    mov         rax, qword ptr [rsp+50h]  
    mov         qword ptr [rsp+30h], rax  
    mov         rax, qword ptr [rsp+30h]  
    add         rax, 30h  
    mov         rcx, qword ptr [rsp+30h]  
    add         rcx, 20h  
    mov         rdx, qword ptr [rsp+30h]  
    mov         rdx, qword ptr [rdx+18h]  
    mov         qword ptr [rsp+38h], rdx  
    mov         r9, rax  
    mov         r8, rcx  
    xor         edx, edx  
    xor         ecx, ecx  
    mov         rax, qword ptr [rsp+38h]  
    call        rax
    mov         rax, qword ptr [rsp+30h]  
    mov         byte ptr [rax+38h], 1  
    add         rsp, 48h  
    ret

NormalRoutineNativeAssembly endp
```

Thanks to everyone who helped me try find the solution to this problem.